# UCANACCESS_HOME system variable

Tags: java, undefined, ucanaccess

I am trying to use Ucanaccess but i get this error:

> The UCANACCESS_HOME system variable isn't defined:  it should be:
>   -DUCANACCESS_HOME=

I have seen that the most common mistake is not having added the .jar files but i did:

[image]

So I dont know how to define that system variable, do I have to define it in code?

Comment: `-DUCANACCESS_HOME=` is a runtime parameter that you give on the command line when you run the program. The `-D` denotes a general property as opposed to the parameters that you mean for the JVM to understand (memory settings, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove ucanload.jar from the Build Path. If you have the other five (5) jar files in there then you don't need ucanload.jar.